# Is it good to have multiple database running in a same project?

Tags: database, database-design

I had read many database design books, but all of them use only **one** database to deal with **a project**.
But I was wondering that is that a good idea to have **multiple** database dealing with the **same project**?

Comment: I wonder if it is necessary in your to have multiple databases? You can already have a nice conception with different roles and profiles affected to the users.
Check this about the performance side : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28614/1459961

Comment: But what if putting all the data in the same database makes database too complex(too many tables inside), is there a good solution to cope with?

Comment: @lijung: How many tables do you consider too many?  Hundreds of tables in a single database is not uncommon.

Comment: This seems like a common question from new database developers, mainly because I think they underestimate just how fast and efficient even massive databases can be.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Now I know that I really underestimate it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.

There are certainly circumstances where it's required or even desirable, but those are for specific use cases.

In general you don't want to for a combination of relational integrity (difficult to enforce across databases) and transactional integrity. There would have to be a really compelling reason to split the datasets to incur the added complexity and maintenance of a separate database instance.

Comment: but what if my project is pretty big? If I put all the tables in the same database, it will be pretty complex. Is there any good solution to deal with it?

Comment: How many tables are there in your DB,I have seen DB having 100+ tables.

Comment: Only about 30 tables... Wow 100+ tables @@. OK, Thanks. Now I know I am in the right path.

Comment: we are also thinking to use the brick system means use one centralization table and rest will be submodule placed on different databases. we have more than 1500 tables. which pattern we need to follow. Single databases or multiple databases.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no.  However...

Reasons you *might* want multiple databases:

1. Different objectives.  e.g. OLAP vs OLTP
2. Different companies, domains or tenants, where you need guarantees that the data between domains will never be commingled.
3. Data archival.

If none of these conditions apply, you probably don't need multiple databases.  Instead, you partition your data by using field id's such as TenantID, CategoryID, etc.

Comment: but you forgot : max connection per db (lmitted by some hosting services ) this is why you should have multiple ones

Comment: That would be a really poor tradeoff.  Find a real hosting provider instead.

Comment: hhhh if i had money i would rent a server and do whatever i want ;)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if one project consumes multiple databases, it is because it must consume different, often legacy sources of information that originated outside of this particular project.  This is most common in Enterprise environments.

If you are creating a new project, create a single database to represent the data associated with that project unless there is a specific, convincing argument to do otherwise.