# Multithreading for queries in SQL Database

Tags: python, sql, database, multithreading, postgresql

Suppose I have a database, for example, for messenger. My app is collecting messages and stores them in my database. It doesn't matter what type of database it is (i want to know how it is usually embodied and does my database support it, and are there other databases that do if it doesn't), but in my case it is PostgreSQL. I'm also using Python psychopg2 adapter. What I want actually is managing all the queries so that they don't interrupt each other.

Let's make clear what I want. Suppose we have two threads, two clients apparently, *that are running in different threads*, and those are loading messages from the database. Client 1 is running:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = client1_id;
```

To select all messages, that he's written, from the database, and then tries to fetch data, but instead, what it becomes, ***I guess***, are all the messages from Client2. What happens now, is this:

```
# in thread 1:
   
  cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = %s;', client1_id)

# in thread 2
   
  cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = %s;', client2_id)   << this is the last SELECT

# then again in thread 1

  cursor.fetchall()                                                          << fetching data from the last select

# and then in thread 2
  
  cursor.fetchall()
```

What * I think is going to happen*, is Client1 will retrieve data from the last select, in this case, it is data from Client2, and that is the question I'm trying to find an answer to.

---

**QUESTION**

*How can I read and write data from my database in different threads, so that every client runs his queries separately from other clients?*

---

As it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28614/12652472), multiple connections aren't this good solution for me, and I think there's no sense in buffering all queries and executing them as a sequence, in a row, when you have, for example, 10000 users. So, what kind of architecture should I use for this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you open a connection in any, it is a good approach to close it and then create a new connection. In the above code you are executing two queries and fetching after the second thread. Now you will get result for on the second thread. The right approach is, create a connection, fetch the result and close the connection on your operation is completed and then open a new connection as alike perform the operation and close it. This approach is very good to follow in any programming language. Below is the sample code,

```
# in thread 1:

   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = %s;', client1_id)

   cursor.fetchall()   
   con.close()   

# in thread 2

   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = %s;', client2_id)   

   cursor.fetchall()
   con.close()
```

Comment: Wow, that could be exactly what i want, thanks. But is it good approach to open and close connection every time? Does it take reasonably more time to proceed? Consider i connect to my database via localhost (my database and my are connected to the same network).

Comment: Yes, its good approach to open and close every time. Because, when you don't close the connections and open a new connection, then multiple connections would be open and database gets locked, since it cannot accept connections in parallel as you are using localhost. It is the best approach to open and close. If you feel this answer is reliable, please mark it as correct answer, so that others may also be helpful

Comment: The main reason why i am bothering is - does it take much time to open and close connection?

Comment: No it will not take much time. It takes same time as you are opening multiple connections.

Answer (score 2):

For modern databases each query will be run in it's separate "space". That means those two queries may return different result sets.

The wikipedia page [Multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) is a good read.

Also, remember that when retrieve data from a database you only get a *copy* of the data; you don't *control* it in your app. The moment you retrieve that data from the database it may already be *stale* since some other thread or app may have modified it already.

Also, I would recommend that in a highly multi-threaded app you should consider the "Version Number Pattern" to detect and control many users updating the same data. Otherwise a badly designed app may end up corrupting the data unintentionally.